# my background image gets moved by an animated div block

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

i have this body with a background

```
body {
    background-image: url(/img/wand2.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
}
```

firstly, i have the problem, that it wont behave as a background. its more like an image, just appearing after all content. but when i animate this div

```
#media {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 19%;
}
```

with this jquery code

```
if($menuopen === false){
    $('#media').animate({
        height: '+=100px'
    });
});
```

my background image just gets pushed away by the div. do you guys know how to avoid this?

edit:
ok i found my mistake. i still had

```
<img src="img/wand2.jpg" style="width:100%;"/>
```

in my body and background-image had to be written like this

```
background-image: url("img/wand2.jpg");
```

to be displayed correctly.

but the question still remains, why media still pushes everything away, for example

```
#mainbox {
    position:fixed ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 60%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

html would be this:

```
<body>
    <div id="header"><div id="welt"></div><div id="helden"></div><a href="#" id="load_home"><div id="home">HOME</div></a><div id="media"></div><div id="impressum"></div></div>
    <div id="mainbox">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle? Or post more code? `$menuopen` means nothing in what you've provided and there's no html

Comment: add `display:inline` to media

Comment: display:inline doesn't work, bot i thought of something like z-index, but cant find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your final question is `why 'media' div is pushes everything away?`, then the answer is simple. It's because here it is positioned statically, which is a default value.

Check the following code snippet which will explain, how different position types are affected by this 'media' div. After that add the following css property for `#media` and run the snippet again,

```
position:absolute;
z-index:9;
```

with above css property applied, 'media' div will not change position of other elements.
You can find a nice comparison between different positioning on [css-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#media').animate({
        height: '+=100px'
    },1000);
});
```

```css
html, body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-position: top;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    clear: both;
}

#mainbox {
    position:fixed ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: white;
}

#media {
    float: left;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 29%;
}

#relative {
    clear: both;
    background-color: red;
 position:relative;
    width: 30%;
}

#absolute {
    clear: both;
    background-color: orange;
 position:absolute;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div id="header">
  <div id="media"></div>
 </div>
    <div id="mainbox">1. fixed position</div>
 <div id="absolute">2. absolute position-1</div>
 <div id="relative">3. relative position</div>
 <div id="absolute">4. absolute position-2</div>
```